a question of gamma distribution and negative binomial
this is the 9th exercise of chapter 7.4 from fundamentals of probability with stochastic process(4th):
a manufacturer produces light bulbs at a poisson rate of 200/hr. the probability that a light bulb is defective is 0.015. during production, the light bulbs are tested and defective ones are put in a special can that holds up to a maximum of 25 light bulbs. on average, how long does it take until the can is filled?
one way to solve the problem is using $$\lambda_{defective}=200*0.015$$ and it matches the answer provided by the author.
what i want to ask is, i tried another method using combination of negative binomial random variables and gamma distribution but the answer turned out to be wrong. but i couldn't find the problems.
$$\sum_{n=25}^\infty {n-1 \choose 25-1}p^{25}q^{n-25}\int_{t=0}^\infty tf(t)dt $$
where p is 0.015(the defective rate) and t represents the gamma random variable with parameter (25, 200)
i just skip the details of calculation and the final answer turned out to be
$$\frac{25*26}{\lambda*p^2}$$
i don't explain my thinking process very clearly, or the whole question will be too long. if you want further clarification. just let me know.
##calculation process:
$$\sum_{n=25}^\infty {n-1 \choose 25-1}p^{25}q^{n-25}\int_{t=0}^\infty tf(t)dt$$
$$= \sum_{n=25}^\infty {n-1 \choose 25-1}p^{25}q^{n-25}\operatorname{E}[T \mid N]$$
$$= \sum_{n=25}^\infty {n-1 \choose 25-1}p^{25}q^{n-25}\frac{n}{\lambda}$$
$$= \frac{1}{\lambda}\sum_{n=25}^\infty \frac{n!}{24!(n-25)!} p^{25}q^{n-25}$$
$$= \frac{25}{\lambda}\sum_{n=25}^\infty {n \choose 25} p^{25}q^{n-25}$$
$$= \frac{25}{\lambda*p}\sum_{n=25}^\infty {n \choose 25} p^{26}q^{n-25}$$
$$= \frac{25}{\lambda*p}\sum_{m=26}^\infty {m-1 \choose 26-1} p^{26}q^{m-26}$$
$$= \frac{25}{\lambda*p}*\frac{26}{p}$$

You've not explained the basis for the expression you wrote, so my initial reaction when I saw it is, "where does this come from?"
Indeed, your expression factors as the product of a sum and an integral:
$$\sum_{n=25}^\infty \binom{n-1}{25-1} p^{25} (1-p)^{n-25} \tag{1}$$
and
$$\int_{t=0}^\infty t f(t) \, dt \tag{2}$$ where I presume $f(t)$ is a gamma density; but the sum $(1)$ equals $1$, so why write it at all?
What I think you are trying to do is the following:  let $X$ count the random number of total light bulbs produced until the $25^{\rm th}$ defective bulb is found.  Then $X \sim \operatorname{NegBinomial}(r = 25, p = 0.015)$, with PMF
$$\Pr[X = x] = \binom{x-1}{25-1} p^{25} (1-p)^{x-25}, \quad x \in \{25, 26, 27, \ldots \}. \tag{3}$$
Now, conditioned on $X = x$ bulbs produced, the total time it took to produce them is a gamma random variable with shape $n = x$ and rate $\lambda = 200$; i.e.,
$$Y \mid X = x \sim \operatorname{Gamma}(n = x, \lambda = 200), \\
f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) = \frac{\lambda^x y^{x-1} e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(x)}, \quad y > 0. \tag{4}$$
We want to compute $\operatorname{E}[Y]$, the unconditional expectation of the total production time.  This is computed via the law of total expectation:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[Y]
&= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{E}[Y \mid X]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{X}{\lambda}\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda} \operatorname{E}[X] \\
&= \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{r}{p} \\
&= \frac{25}{200 \cdot 0.015} = \frac{25}{3}. \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
In the second line, we used the fact that the mean of a gamma random variable with shape $n$ and rate $\lambda$ is $n/\lambda$.  In the fourth line, we used the fact that the mean of a negative binomial random variable with parameters $r$ and $p$ is $r/p$, using the parametrization described in $(3)$.
Our answer makes intuitive sense:  if on average, $\lambda = 200$ bulbs are produced per hour, and $0.015$ of these are defective, then about $3$ bulbs per hour will be defective, and it will take on average $25/3$ hours to produce $25$ defective bulbs.
What you seem to have tried to do is explicitly calculate $\operatorname{E}[Y]$ using the PMF and densities $(3)$ and $(4)$.  But this is not necessary; moreover, you didn't correctly incorporate the fact that the gamma density is conditioned on the outcome of the negative binomial random variable.
One remaining question is, what is the unconditional distribution of $Y$?  That is to say, we calculated the expectation, but what is $f_Y(y)$?  This is not the same as $f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)$.  To calculate it, we would write (this time, using the law of total probability)
$$\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \sum_{x=25}^\infty f_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) \Pr[X = x] \\
&= \sum_{x=25}^\infty \binom{x-1}{25-1}p^{25}(1-p)^{x-25} \frac{\lambda^x y^{x-1} e^{-\lambda y}}{\Gamma(x)} \\
&= p^{25} e^{-\lambda y} \sum_{x=25}^\infty \frac{(x-1)!}{24! \, (x-25)! \, (x-1)!} (1-p)^{x-25} \lambda^x y^{x-1} \\
&= \frac{p^{25} e^{-\lambda y}}{24!} \sum_{x=25}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda y)^{x-25}}{(x-25)!} \lambda^{25} y^{24} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda p)^{25} y^{24} e^{-\lambda y}}{24!} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda y)^k}{k!} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda p)^{25} y^{24} e^{-\lambda y}}{24!} e^{(1-p)\lambda y} \\
&= \frac{(\lambda p)^{25} y^{24} e^{-\lambda p y}}{\Gamma(25)}. \tag{6}
\end{align}$$
Consequently, we have shown that the unconditional distribution of $Y$ is gamma, with shape $25$ and rate $\lambda p$.  This is consistent with our earlier computations, and in general, the idea of Poisson thinning.  That is to say, the original process is thinned in order to count the production of defective bulbs, creating a new homogeneous Poisson process with reduced intensity $\lambda p$.

your answer is very clear and reasonable to me! i am sorry i didn't write out my thinking process and calculation clearly(but your interpretation is totally right!). so i edit my question and add the whole process. i think i might made some logic or calculation fault but i cannot find it (i guess the problems lies on dependency?) would you please take a look? thank you!

@SoDude Everything you did up to the last step is correct.  All that you are missing is that $$\sum_{m=26}^\infty \binom{m - 1}{26 - 1} p^{26} q^{m-26} = 1.$$  It's not an expectation.  It's just the sum of a negative binomial PMF with parameters $r = 26$ and $p$.

god! such a stupid mistake. thank you for your help!
